# How to post json and file objects in a single web api ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Here is my controller's method

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("SignInRecords")]
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SignInRecords> AddSignInRecords([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromBody] StudentDetailsViewModel body, [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromForm] IFormFile File)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();        
    }
```

> But It fail to invoke api, Saying Unsupported Media Type:415

[image: API response]

Comment: Try with adding IFormFile File in StudentDetailsViewModel  as property and remove FromBody from parameter.

Comment: @RahulMistry, I have tried it will work as FromForm but I want to pass json in body not in key value pair as a form.

Comment: No, you could not combine `FromForm` and `FromBody`, `FromForm` correspond to `form-data`, `Frombody` correspond to `application/json`, you only could specify one content-type for the request. For uploading file, you would be better to use `FromForm`, otherwise, you need to convert the `File` object to byte string at client side, and then send to server.